# Decorator pattern : Detaching responsibilities

Tags: c++, design-patterns, decorator

For Decorator design pattern, GoF clearly states that :

> With decorators, responsibilities can be added and removed at run-time
>   simply by attaching and detaching them.

I am trying to build a skeleton code in C++ where I can easily see how this pattern can add responsibilities to an undecorated object.

My question is how can I remove a particular responsibility. Removing the last wrapped responsibility can be done easily. But can I also remove a responsility added in between.

Here is my sample code :

```
class Icecream { //Component
    public :
    virtual void addToppings() = 0 ;
    virtual Icecream *getUndecorated() = 0 ;
} ;
class PlainIcecream : public Icecream { //Concrete Component
    public :
    void addToppings() { cout<<"I am just plain icecream, you may add more flavors\n" ; }
    Icecream * getUndecorated() {return this ; }
} ;
class Topping : public Icecream { //Decorator
    protected :
    Icecream *icecream ;
    public :
    Topping(Icecream *i) : icecream(i) {}
    void addToppings() { icecream->addToppings() ; }
} ; 
class PeanutToppings : public Topping { //Concrete Component A
    public :
    PeanutToppings(Icecream *i) : Topping(i) {}
    void addToppings() {
        Topping::addToppings() ;
        cout<<"Adding peanut toppings for great taste\n" ; 
    }
    Icecream * getUndecorated() {return icecream ; }
} ;
class CandyToppings : public Topping { //Concrete Component A
    public :
    CandyToppings(Icecream *i) : Topping(i) {}
    void addToppings() {
        Topping::addToppings() ;
        cout<<"Adding candy toppings for yummy flavour\n" ;
    }
    Icecream * getUndecorated() {return icecream ; }
} ;
main() {
    Icecream *icecream_with_candy_and_peanuts = new CandyToppings(new PeanutToppings(new PlainIcecream)) ;
    icecream_with_candy_and_peanuts->addToppings() ;
    cout<<"_________________________________________________\n" ;
    Icecream *icecream_with_only_peanuts = icecream_with_candy_and_peanuts->getUndecorated() ;
    icecream_with_only_peanuts->addToppings() ;
    cout<<"_________________________________________________\n" ;
    Icecream *icecream_plain = icecream_with_only_peanuts->getUndecorated() ;
    icecream_plain->addToppings() ;
}
```

Now I want to know if it is possible to have an icecream with only candy topping from `icecream_with_candy_and_peanuts`. Please do not consider why do I want to do so. I am just trying to understand the term

> detaching responsibilities

as mentioned in GoF.

Comment: Your design seems flawed, as a topping isn't really an ice cream. Remember that inheritance is an "is a" relationship.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude, you can consider them as base, derived classes. I have mentioned already that the concern is not the class names, the concern is abt detaching responsibility from decorated object as mentioned in GoF. You can name these classes as you want to name them

Comment: @ Some programmer dude it is the skeleton that I want you to consider and class names have no significance at all here

Comment: @user3282758 Good question. I have never before used the *Decorator* pattern to *detach* responsibilities but it's definitely a valid use case for the pattern. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Removing the last wrapped responsibility can be done easily

There is no need to have a separate `getUndecorated` method. This is not a part of the standard *Decorator* pattern definition.

> Now I want to know if it is possible to have an icecream with only candy topping from icecream_with_candy_and_peanuts

Yes you can. There is not much of a difference between *attaching* or *detaching* responsibilities when it comes to the decorator pattern. To *detach* a responsibility, you just need to recreate your component again :

```
//attaching responsibilities
Icecream *icecream = new new PlainIcecream();
*icecream = new PeanutToppings(icecream);//wrap around with new respnsibility
*icecream = new CandyToppings(icecream);//wrap around with new responsiblity

//detaching responsibilities
*icecream = new CandyToppings(new PlainIcecream());
```

Notice how I am using `*icecream` in both the cases. You are able to *attach* and *detach* responsibilities by confining to a single interface (i.e `IceCream`). That's the idea behind the *Decorator* pattern.

That said, the *Composite* pattern implemented using a `HashMap` (where key is the topping name) would be a better choice in a scenario where you want to be able to arbitrarily add or remove responsibilities from an existing instance.

Bonus tips : The decorator in the *Decorator* pattern should ideally not be instantiable (`Toppings` in your case). It would also help to rename `Toppings` to `ToppingsDecorator` instead. (I understand this is not the direct question you are asking. This is purely for the benefit of other readers)

Comment: your answer is well written. But I still have a query, that is, you are creating a new instance and referring this new instance with the same pointer. Does that means the original object referred by `icecream` pointer can not have reduced responsibilities

Comment: @user3282758 The idea behind the decorator pattern is to *wrap* an object with responsibilities. To do this *wrapping*, you need to create a new instance that *wraps* new responsibilities around the old instance (regardless of whether you are *attaching* or *detaching* responsibilities) The reason why this is not clear to you is because you *attached* responsibilities in one step. See my edit where we *attach* and *detach* responsibilities to the original `*icecream*. Note that my C++ is rusty so my answer may not be correct syntactically. Please feel free to edit the answer and remove errors

Comment: @user3282758 The *Composite* pattern could be a better choice for this use case. See edit.